# How can I find the following integral for $f(r) = r * e^{-r^2 K}$?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

[image]
There are a function $f(r)$.
I would like to find the $\int\int_A f(r)drd\theta$

How can I find it?
$f(r) = r * e^{-r^2 K}$

$K$ is just a variable.

Comment: Can you write the region in terms of polar coordinates $r,\theta$?

Comment: Is K really a variable, or do you mean it is constant independent of $r$?

Comment: K is constant independent of r

Comment: I don't know how can I write the region a in polar coordinates. x, y are just variables.